# ES6 Array spread operator with nullish coalescing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm getting the `Expression expected` error when I try this:

```
const func = () => [0, 1]
const possibly_undefined_var = { var: 3 }

const var = [possibly_undefined_var?.var ?? ...func()]
```

Expected result: [3] or [0, 1]

I was wondering if there is any way to use the array spread operator along with nullish coalescing in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the clearest way to do this would be to use the conditional operator:

```
const obj = possibly_undefined_var?.var;
const arr = obj ? [obj] : [...func()];
```

I can't think of any good way to alternate `obj` with a spread of `func` inside a single array literal that isn't unnecessarily confusing and verbose (and would require the conditional operator anyway, I think).

If `obj` can be falsey without being null or undefined, then it takes a bit more code:

```
const obj = possibly_undefined_var?.var;
const arr = (obj === null || obj === undefined) ? [...func()] : [obj];
```

Comment: `obj == null` handles both `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, you can do that too, but I prefer to avoid `==` in all cases, `===` has many fewer gotchas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons